# Laravel controller trigger modal to show data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, modal-dialog

So I have this code where originally if I press the button it will open a page showing detail about items, but I want it just to show it in modal. is that any possible?

my index inside controller

```php
public function index(SubOrder $order)
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
    
    $items = $order->items;
    $tokoId = Toko::select('id')->firstWhere('user_id', auth()->id())->id;
    $orders = SubOrder::where('toko_id', $tokoId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    
    return view('sellers.order.backup', compact('items','orders'));
}
```

the show function inside the same controller

```php
public function show(SubOrder $order)
{
    $items = $order->items;
    
    return view('sellers.order.show', compact('items'));
}
```

the index blade

```xml
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Create</th>
      <th>Detail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @forelse ($orders as $subOrder)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$subOrder->created_at}}</td>
        <td>
          <a name="" id="" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{{route('seller.orders.show', $subOrder)}}" role="button">Detail Pesanan</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    @empty
    @endforelse
  </tbody>
</table>
```

while the show blade is

```xml
<table class="table table-striped" style="padding-bottom: 50px">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Nama Barang</th>
      <th>Jumlah</th>
      <th>Harga</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($items as $item)
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">{{$item->nama}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->pivot->jumlah}}</td>
        <td>@currency($item->pivot->harga)</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this code works fine, but I want it just show the detail in the modal. tried it before where I just copy paste the show blade code to the modal body and not working. help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy and dirty way to do this would be a second `@foreach` to create every details modal on the same view.

```xml
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Create</th>
      <th>Detail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @forelse ($orders as $subOrder)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $subOrder->created_at }}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-modal-{{ $order->id }}">
            Detail Pesanan
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    @empty
    @endforelse
  </tbody>
</table>

@foreach ($orders as $subOrder)
  <div id="details-modal-{{ $order->id }}" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-modal-{{ $order->id }}" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="table table-striped" style="padding-bottom: 50px">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th>Nama Barang</th>
                <th>Jumlah</th>
                <th>Harga</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach ($subOrder->items as $item)
                <tr>
                  <td scope="row">{{ $item->nama }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->pivot->jumlah }}</td>
                  <td>@currency($item->pivot->harga)</td>
                </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Make sure you eager load the items relationship in your index method.

```php
$orders = SubOrder::with('items')->where('toko_id', $tokoId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

---

Another possibility is to make a single modal, and use its events to query the server for the view that should be loaded inside.

```xml
<!-- Button in table -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-modal" data-order="{{ $subOrder->id }}">
  Detail Pesanan
</button>
```

```xml
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="details-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-modal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
// Script
$('#details-modal').on('show.bs.modal', event => {
  var order = $(event.relatedTarget).data('order');
  modalBody = $(this).find('.modal-body');
  // show loading spinner while waiting for ajax to be done
  modalBody.html(`
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `);

  $.ajax({
    url: `/orders/${order}`, // the url for your show method
    method: 'get'
  })
  .done(view => modalBody.html(view));
  .fail(error => console.error(error));
});
```

Make sure your `show.blade` is ONLY the `<table>` (no @extends, @section or anything else).

Comment: tried the 2nd one and not working for me. but tried the first one and it works as I wanted. thank you very much!

Comment: I just realize I got this bug where eachtime after I close the modal the layout moved abit to the left. do you know why?

Comment: I don't. Perhaps you have an unclosed <div> element or an extra </div> somewhere. Try indenting your html thoroughly to see if there's nothing weird. You could also do right click -> view page source and check if your browser highlights anything in red. Also, I remember reading somewhere that bootstrap modals worked better if they were placed at the end of the body, right before the <script> tags.